# MySQL update value +1 (increment) on button click

Tags: php, mysql

I know this question has been answered over a million times, but I'm very new to the whole programming scene and I just can't get it to work. Sorry, I hope you can help me!

**HTML:**

```
<div class="the_score">+76</div>
<div id="increment_value">Like</div>
```

I have a MySQL connection and I can fetch the data, but I want the score to update with +1 when someone clicks the Like div. I have a table "websites" with row "WebScore" that has the function int(10) (?? I hope that is correct).

I use this to fetch the data and show it on my website:

```
$r = rand(2,3);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM websites WHERE ID = $r";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume you have a *column*, not a *row*, called WebScore.

You need the query

```
 UPDATE websites SET WebScore = WebScore + 1 WHERE ID = $r
```

As you can see, it finds the right row of your table and updates the value of the WebScore column.

This sort of things can only be done from a PHP program. It can't be done directly from a Javascript method invoked within a web browser. So, if you want to react to a user click, you'll need to post a form or invoke an Ajax style call to a php endpoint. How to do that is the province of another question.

Keep plugging away; you'll figure out this database stuff.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! But how do I get this triggered by the click on the div? I did this now but once more I'm stuck:

onclick="update_value.php"

and I created update_value.php:

<?php
 $update = "UPDATE websites SET WebScore = WebScore + 1 WHERE ID = $r"
 query($update);
?>